# Add element to end of tuple list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

Im a new in haskell and i try to add element to end of tuple list

For example:

[(1,2,3),(2,3,4)]  i want to add (3,4,5)  . [(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(3,4,5)]

Comment: what did you try, have you used a search engine or something? Being new to haskell - do you know about www.learnyouahaskell.com, a great introduction?

Comment: Off topic because we need the: "Minimal understanding close reason back." No effort has been put into even attempting to solve the problem.

Comment: I did a google search and ended up here. So thank you for asking this question

Answer (score 6):

Adding to the end of a list is inefficient but you can use `++`:

```
[(1,2,3),(2,3,4)] ++ [(3,4,5)]
```

If you need to keep adding to the end of your collection you could use `Data.Sequence` instead:

```
import Data.Sequence
(fromList [(1,2,3),(2,3,4)]) |> (3,4,5)
```

Comment: Or a diff list. Or `(:)` onto the front and reverse once when you're done. Both are constant time with a single O(n) to "finalize" the list.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this

```
[(1,2,3),(2,3,4)] ++ [(3,4,5)]
```

`(++)` will concatenate two lists to create another list.